# Can you shift an easyJet flight booking to another account?

Tags: tickets, easyjet

I know that you can change the name on a booking, but I assume that doing so still leaves the booking in my account. If I want to entirely give the flight to another person, then I'd prefer that the booking end up in their account so that they have complete control over it, and I'm no longer involved.

I can't find anything saying whether this is possible.

Is it possible?

Comment: You will still know the booking reference so you'll still be in control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Contact [easyJet Customer Service](https://www.easyjet.com/en/help/contact) if you want to get it done.**

If you decide to do so, prepare a solid explanation of why you need to do it and what's the relationship between the two accounts involved. If you're also trying to get the passenger's name changed at the same time, easyJet will likely suspect that you're trying to re-sell the ticket. You'll have to convince them otherwise. Resale is strictly prohibited by paragraph 6.5 of the [Terms and Conditions](https://www.easyjet.com/en/terms-and-conditions) and will likely lead to cancellation of the booking without a right to a refund:

> 6.5: You cannot resell your ticket to someone else. We reserve the right to cancel any Booking, without a refund, **if we reasonably believe it may have been resold** or made available for resale (including, but not limited to, via any online marketplace).

Answer (score 0):

This isn’t allowed, according to the [Ts&C’s paragraph 6.5](http://You%20cannot%20resell%20your%20ticket%20to%20someone%20else.%20We%20reserve%20the%20right%20to%20cancel%20any%20Booking,%20without%20a%20refund,%20if%20we%20reasonably%20believe%20it%20may%20have%20been%20resold%20or%20made%20available%20for%20resale%20(including,%20but%20not%20limited%20to,%20via%20any%20online%20marketplace).):

> You cannot resell your ticket to someone else. We reserve the right to cancel any Booking, without a refund, if we reasonably believe it may have been resold or made available for resale (including, but not limited to, via any online marketplace).

(From the comments)